# Array tkinter Entry to Label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hey Guys I am beginner and working on Project Linear and Binary search GUI application using Tkinter, I want to add multiple Entry boxes values to label and in an array here, I tried but its not working fine:

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Looping of entry box")
root.geometry("1200x600")

def ApplytoLabel():
    xx=size.get()
    for i in range(xx):
        ArrayLabel=tk.Label(root,text="Array Element")
        ArrayLabel.pack()

def Boxes():
    xx=size.get()
    for i in range(xx):        
        box=tk.Entry(root)
        box.pack()
    ApplytoLabel1=tk.Button(root,text="Submit To Array",command=ApplytoLabel)
    ApplytoLabel1.pack()




Array = tk.Frame(root)
Array.pack()

text1=tk.Label(Array,text="Enter the Size of Array:",
               font="Arial 10 bold",fg="blue")
text1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="w")

size=tk.IntVar()

ArraySize=tk.Entry(Array,textvariable=size)
ArraySize.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="w")

SizeofArray=tk.Button(Array,text="Submit",command=Boxes)
SizeofArray.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky="w")





root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well; it's not working fine is not much of a problem description but I'm going to guess you want to keep the array elements in some way. The usual way to do this is to create a list and then add the Entrys to the list as you create them.

When you create the Labels you simply read the values from the list of Entrys as they have the same index as the Labels. Part of the code:

```
def ApplytoLabel():
    xx=size.get()
    for i in range(xx):
        element = box_list[i].get() # Get value from corresponding Entry
        ArrayLabel=tk.Label(root,text="Array Element: " + element)
        ArrayLabel.pack()

box_list = []   # Create list of Entrys
def Boxes():
    xx=size.get()
    for i in range(xx):        
        box=tk.Entry(root)
        box.pack()
        box_list.append(box)    # Append current Entry to list
    ApplytoLabel1=tk.Button(root,text="Submit To Array",command=ApplytoLabel)
    ApplytoLabel1.pack()
```

Comment: It worked, now I want to make it efficient before going to second box it should be necessary to add value in first box...

Comment: That can be done but the code will be a lot more complicated. You will basically have to capture any shift of focus to any of the dynamically created entries and then handle that in whatever way you want to. It would be a lot easier to check all the entries when the user presses "Submit To Array" button.