# How can I avoid TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str when configuring a label array in python tkinter?

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter, label

I created a label array, when I try to configure the text changing it I got the error:

> TypeAError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

even if I enter a pure string in the configure. Anybody can help understand why?

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
for i in range(5):
    ArrayLabel=tk.Label(root,text="Array Label")
    ArrayLabel.pack()      
for i in range(5):
    ArrayLabel[i].configure(text="Change")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: `ArrayLabel[i]` seems suspicious. `ArrayLabel` is a single label, not a list of labels.

Comment: Make a list and append the labels to list and then use indexing of list

Comment: full traceback is the following:                                                                        
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\TEMP\PROVAlbARAY.py", line 10, in <module>
    ArrayLabel[i].configure(text="i")
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1489, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: originally I tried to comment the following but I couldn't comment due to my novelty here, so I opened a new question: 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53079086/array-tkinter-entry-to-label

Comment: >>>ArrayLabel[i] seems suspicious. ArrayLabel is a single label, not a list of labels.              I agree, but if I try:    for i in range(5):
        ArrayLabel[i]=tk.Label(root,text="Array Label")
        ArrayLabel[i].pack()                                                                                                    I get the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\TEMP\PROVAlbARAY.py", line 6, in <module>
    ArrayLabel[i]=tk.Label(root,text="Array Label")
NameError: name 'ArrayLabel' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
labels_array = []

for i in range(5):
    label = tk.Label(root,text="Array Label")
    label.pack()
    labels_array.append(label)

for i in range(5):
    labels_array[i].configure(text="Change")

# Even better:
for label in labels_array:
    label.configure(text="Change")

root.mainloop()
```

You need to make an empty array and append it with all of the labels. After that you need to loop over the array and call `.configure` to each label.

Answer (score 0):

> TypeAError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Never looping again on line 4.

- Add `root.after`
- add `root.update`
- Comment out the second looping.
- Add `.configure` w/out index

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

for i in range(5):
    ArrayLabel=tk.Label(root,text="Array Label")
    ArrayLabel.pack()
    
    root.after(1000)
    root.update()
    
    ArrayLabel.configure(text="Change")
     
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]